# Cannot create a new WordPress Post after Forminator Form Submission using php action hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a Forminator Form on my WordPress Site and I want to allow users to create new posts after submitting it. I used Custom Post Type UI Plugin to create a custom slug for the newly created posts. Next, I have written short php code to execute an action after the users submit the form and I have added it to the functions.php file. Below I am providing more information about the names & ids of my fields:
Forminator Form ID: 761
Forminator Text Area field name: textarea-1
Custom slug name: view-test-posts
Redirect users to the newly created post after form submission

```
add_action('forminator_custom_form_submit', 'create_post_and_redirect', 10, 2);

function create_post_and_redirect($form_id, $data) {
    // Check if the form ID matches
    if ($form_id === 761) {
        // Get the submitted textarea value
        $textarea_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['textarea-1']);

        // Create a new post
        $post_data = array(
            'post_title'    => 'New Test Post',
            'post_content'  => $textarea_value,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'view-test-posts', // The custom post type slug
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

        // Check if the post was inserted successfully
        if (!is_wp_error($post_id)) {
            // Get the URL of the newly created post
            $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);

            // Redirect to the newly created post URL after successful submission
            wp_redirect($post_url);
            exit; 
        } else {
            // Handle the error if the post creation fails
            $error_message = 'Error creating post: ' . $post_id->get_error_message();
            wp_die($error_message);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I submit the form, a new post is not created & I am not redirected to any page. I have tried switching off all plugins except Forminator, Elementor and Custom Post Type UI and the issue remain.
Something important to note is that, the form is submitted successfully, and I can see the information under the Submissions section of the Forminator Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
function create_post_and_redirect($form_id, $data) {
    if ($form_id === 761 && isset($_POST['textarea-1']) && !empty($_POST['textarea-1'])) {
        $textarea_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['textarea-1']);

        $post_data = array(
            'post_title'    => 'New Test Post',
            'post_content'  => $textarea_value,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'view-test-posts', // The custom post type slug
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

        if (!is_wp_error($post_id)) {
            $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);

            wp_redirect($post_url);
            exit; 
        } else {
            $error_message = 'Error creating post: ' . $post_id->get_error_message();
            wp_die($error_message);
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', function() {
    create_post_and_redirect(761, $_POST);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).